Why does my outdoor light sensor not turn the lights off during the day?
Bought our house just over a year ago, and the outdoor lighting has a Tork 2021 Photocontrol sensor (pic attached below) that has been working absolutely great until about a month or so ago. The lights are constantly on, and haven't been turning off during the day.
I've tried to find troubleshooting guides for this specific product but haven't been able to find anything. Is this issue something that can be fixed by replacing a certain piece in the housing, or will this require a total replacement? 

Is the picture your sensor, or is it from some catalog? The sensor looks quite new on the photo.

Have you manually power-cycled it?  Some brands will go into "on" mode instead of sensor mode when the switch is turned off and on quickly.  The down side is that if you don't have a switch hooked up to it, and the power flickers, it can get stuck on.

At ~ $18 each (current price at Home Depot and on Amazon), there are unlikely to be any practical replacement parts - i.e., you just treat the entire thing as a replaceable module.
The only real troubleshooting is to (a) make sure the photocell cover is clean (if it is dirty that could look like "always dark") and (b) try shining a light directly on the photocell to see if it turns the circuit off. If that doesn't help, replace the entire unit. It is a currently available (so no hunting for old stock or for "compatible" items), relatively inexpensive
product from an established manufacturer (i.e., no reason to try to figure out an alternative).

Thanks. Tried both and they didn’t turn off. Just going to replace.
